# checkbox count with select all

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to create the Checkbox count with select all option, it works when each checkbox i select the count was working but when select all option its not working i'm implementing in ASP.NET MVC, Here is my code
**javascript**

```
var countChecked = function () {
        var n = $('input[name="DocNames"]:checked').length;
        $("#span").text(n + (n === 1 ? " document is" : " documents are") + " checked!");
    };
    countChecked();
    $('input[name="DocNames"]').on("click", countChecked);

    $('#select_all').click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td input[name="DocNames"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    })
```

**html code**

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Documnet Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" />Select All</label></td>
</tr>
@if (Model.Documents != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Documents)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="DocNames" value="@item.DocumentName.Trim()" />
                    @item.DocumentName.Trim()
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
else
{

    <tr>
        <td>@ViewBag.NoDocuments</td>
    </tr>
}
```

```
<div id="span"></div>
```

Comment: Either call `countChecked` or trigger a `click` event in the "select all" click handler.

Comment: Simply call `countChecked()` function inside click handler of `select_all` element: `$('#select_all').click(function () { ...; countChecked(); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not yet solved your issue with @Andreas's suggestion (which is the correct answer), I will phrase it again in an answer format:

In your code, you called countChecked() on the click-event of each of the checkboxes. And hence, countChecked() does what it does.

But in your event handler for the SelectAll checkbox, you are forgetting to again call countChecked().

So you have to either call it at the end of your code, like so:

```
$('#select_all').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('td input[name="DocNames"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    countChecked();
})
```

Or, more clumsily, trigger the event of click for any of your checkboxes.

But the above is the best.

Comment: @Amarnath, Not a worry.